# not able to acess variable set in constructor

Tags: javascript, oop

can anyone please advise as what may be wrong with this code? 
The variable that's set in constructor is only accessible upon object creation, but once I call one of the object's methods the variable is no longer accessible.

```
function Animal(name) {
      this.name = name
}

Animal.prototype = (function() 
{
    var i = 0;
    var sitdown = function() {
                      console.log(this.name + ' sits down.');
                      standup();
                  };
    var standup = function (){
                      console.log(this.name+' stands up');
                      if(i != 10)
                      {
                        i++;
                        sitdown();
                      }
                  };
    return {
        standup: standup
    }
})();

var Tiger = new Animal("Tiger");
Tiger.standup();
```

**output:**

```
Tiger stands up 
 sits down. 
 stands up 
 sits down. 
 .......
 ....... 
 stands up 
 sits down. 
 stands up
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you call sitdown() instead of instance.sitdown(); the funtion loses the information about what "this" is and can no longer retrieve the name. It works in the first call because you call Tiger.standup(); The function knows that you are calling this from Tiger.

Comment: Why do you do `standup.call(this);` but then `sitdown();` only?

Comment: apologies it was just a mistake.. I was trying a different approach of accessing the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'this' only contains the object reference, if you either

- call the function using method syntax, e.g. `this.sitdown()`
- or you call it with call()/apply(), as you do in sitdown(): `standup.call(this)`.

Your standup() method calls sitdown() as a function, not as a method, and that won't work.

Comment: `this.sitdown()` will not work, unless you expose `sitdown` in the prototype.

Comment: True, for sitdown() you need call().

Comment: ok thanks for the solution so I have added .call(this) to both standup and sitdown methods and it's now working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Except the first invocation of `standup`, `this` points to window, not to `Tiger`. The problem is, in `standup` you call `sitdown()`. Instead you should call `sitdown.call(this)`.